# find and sort query with mongoose not working in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to sort and limit the the result from find  query. But it is not working, if I am using only find its working fine .

```
this.contentModel.find({}).sort('_id').limit(ContentDAO.pageLimit).exec({
    function(err, data) {

        console.log(data)

        cb(err, data);
    }
})
```

Comment: I think maybe this should just be closed. It's a lexical mistake and that the asker solved themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It worked I was having extra in exec call {}

```
this.contentModel.find({}).sort('_id').limit(ContentDAO.pageLimit).exec(
    function(err, data) {

        console.log(data)

        cb(err, data);
    }

)
```